# How to match full sentence and also word in that sentence both in single regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So I want to match 2 things in my regex, my sentence is: **"I love white cats"** and I want 2 matches from that sentence first the whole sentence as **"I love white cats"** and second match I want is just word: **"white cats"**.

I have tried many regex but they either match "white cats" or "I love white cats" but not both, so if anyone can help me for regex it will be great.

**Edit:** I want to build regex using dynamic sentences, like I will have array of sentences and from that I have to build regex so the array will be like:

```
["I love white cats", "white cats", "something else"]
```

I want to build regex such so that it matches the full sentences and also matches other sentence or words in it. example is the simple version because of complexity in original code.

I have tried regex as below:

```js
const sentence = "I love white cats";
const regex = /(\bI love white cats\b|\bwhite cats\b)/gi;
const matches = sentence.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: How about `const regex = /I love (white cats)/;`?

Comment: @Andy it only gives one match either for `white cats` or `I love white cats` but I want both at the same time

Comment: remove the `g`, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value) *'If the g flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups are not included.'*

Comment: [I'm getting both matches](https://jsfiddle.net/p2yfebmj/).

Comment: @pilchard but isnt `g` is global identifier which means it will not return after first match but match all other cases ? it also show the same in regex101.com

Comment: @Andy but I am matching so many things also so I cant use that simple regex because I also have to match whole paragraph also

Comment: Your _question_ is about just _two_ matches. @HaritsinhGohil. We can't answer a completely different question to the one you've written. You should edit your question with your exact requirements.

Comment: If you basically want independent matching of your "patterns", why not simply do it: iterate through your input array and match every item individually?

Comment: @markalex that consumes so much memory and cpu, here I have shown simple example but in real there will be so lengthy text and so many strings and sentences to match

Comment: Call me old fashioned but isn't it either or ? `(I[ ]love[ ]white[ ]cats)|(white[ ]cats)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve of behavior similar to described with help of capturing groups inside of lookahead.

```js
const sentence = "I love white cats";
const patterns = ["I love white cats", "white cats", "something else"];
const regex = new RegExp(
    '(?=(\\b' + patterns.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b))',
    'gi');
console.log(regex);
const matches = Array.from(sentence.matchAll(regex), (m) => m[1]);
console.log(matches);
```

Demo of generated regex can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/XLbLuB/1).

Notice: this solution has a caveat. If among your `patterns` there is a pattern that starts with full another pattern, only one will be found (depending on there sequence in array).

For example patterns `["I love", "I love white cats"]` will produce a single match `I love`.